# Google Sheets Count Amount of Cells Imported by ImportXML

Tags: google-sheets

I'm attempting to build a database for information about musicians using IMPORTXML, based on http://azlyrics.com. However, it does not contain the amount of songs in each album, so I am attempting to count the amount of links between each `<div class="album">`.

[image]

I tried adding LEN to the front of IMPORTXML, but that returns the length of the first song's name. I tried using COUNT, but that just returns 0. I've researched this extensively, but I couldn't find anything. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Formula: =IMPORTXML(C2, CONCATENATE("/html/body[@class='margin50']/div[@class='container main-page']/div[@class='row']/div[@class='col-xs-12 col-md-6 text-center']/div[@id='listAlbum']/a[following-sibling::div/b[contains(text(), """, F2, """)] and preceding-sibling::div/b[contains(text(), """, E2, """)]]"))

F2 = Bee Gees' 1st
E2 = Monday's Rain

Comment: @pnuts I'm sorry, it's been edited in

Comment: @pnuts Thank you so much! That worked perfectly

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't reproduce your code, but if you want to count the number of strings returned with your importxml statement you can wrap your IMPORTXML() statement with COUNTUNIQUE()